# Xamarin Forms Webpage call never returns result

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have this code:

```
public async Task<List<Template>> GetTemplates(User user)
{
    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("un", user.Username));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pw", user.Password));
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
    var weburl = "myapp.org/get_templates.php";
    var response = await PostResponseTemplates<Template>(weburl, content);

    return response;
}

public async Task<List<Template>> PostResponseTemplates<List>(string weburl, FormUrlEncodedContent content)
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);
    var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    .......
}
```

But the webcall never returns the result after this line: `var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);`.

What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE

Here is the void where I call the function right now:

```
public MemeTemplateList()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LoadTemplateList();
}
private void LoadTemplateList()
{
    var templateList = App.RestService.GetTemplates(App.User);
    ....
```

How to create this async and run it in the page constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing async-await and blocking calls like `.Result`

```
public async Task<List<Template>> PostResponseTemplates<List>(string weburl, FormUrlEncodedContent content) {
    var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);
    var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //<--THIS WILL DEADLOCK

    //...omitted for brevity
```

can cause deadlock. Which is why the function does not return.

Remove `.Result` and make the code async all the way though

```
public async Task<List<Template>> PostResponseTemplates<List>(string weburl, FormUrlEncodedContent content) {
    var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //<--THIS

    //...omitted for brevity
```

I would also suggest changing the function definition from being generic

```
public async Task<List<Template>> PostResponseTemplates(string weburl, FormUrlEncodedContent content) {
    //...
}
```

Since the type is already known within the function

```
List<Template> response = await PostResponseTemplates(weburl, content);
```

Finally make sure everything is async all the way up the call stack

```
public MemeTemplateList() {
    InitializeComponent();
    //Subscribe to event
    loadingTemplates += onLoadingTemplates;
    //raise the event to load the templates.
    LoadTemplateList();
}

private event EventHandler loadingTemplates = delegate { };

//ASYNC VOID ONLY ALLOWED ON EVENT HANDLER!!!!!!!
private async void onLoadingTemplates(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    List<Template> templateList = await App.RestService.GetTemplates(App.User);

    //....
}

private void LoadTemplateList() {
    loadingTemplates(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)